# Split file into different parts based on the data using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to split the data in file 1 based on it´s data in $4 using awk. The target file-names should be taken from a mapping file 2.

File 1

> text;text;text;AB;text
>   text;text;text;AB;text
>   text;text;text;CD;text
>   text;text;text;CD;text
>   text;text;text;EF;text
>   text;text;text;EF;text

File 2

> AB;valid
>   CD;not_valid
>   EF;not_specified

Desired output where the file names are the value of $2 in file 2.

File valid

> text;text;text;AB;text
>   text;text;text;AB;text

File not_valid

> text;text;text;CD;text
>   text;text;text;CD;text

File not_specified

> text;text;text;EF;text
>   text;text;text;EF;text

Any suggestions on how to perform the split?

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} $4 in a {print > a[$4]}
           $4 != p {if (p) close(a[p]); p=$4}' file2 file1
```

Comment: +1: Though better to use `>>` and add `close(a[$4])` too prevent to many open files.

Comment: @jaypal: Thanks but why would `>>` be better here since `>` also behaves same inside `awk`

Comment: When you'll add `close(..)` the next time `awk` opens the file it will overwrite it. Without `close(..)` chances are there will be too many open files error.

Comment: Sure, there is a downside to both actually. With `close` we are opening and closing the files for each line.

Comment: Yes opening and closing is definitely there but closing them in `END` might be too late if there are huge number of open files.

Comment: FWIW GNU awk handles file closure for you so no need to do it manually.You could just close the prev output file every time $4 changes, should work particularly well in this case since the input appears to be sorted on $4.

Comment: SOunds good but get rid of the `p &&` in the condition `p && $4 != p` as it will stop `p` from ever being populated and the `close(p)` will simply do nothing when `p` isn't populated.

Comment: Oh yes. That was a silly mistake on my part. Fixed now. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need the `if (p)` in `if (p) close(p)` as `close(p)` alone will work just fine. From the gawk manual: `close() will silently do nothing if given an argument that does not represent a file, pipe or coprocess that was opened with a redirection.`

Comment: Oh, and it should be `close(a[p])` not `close(p)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that just the first part of the code will work:

```
awk -F';' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2;next} $4 in a {print > a[$4]}' file2 file1
```

So, why the last half code:

```
$4 != p {if (p) close(a[p]); p=$4
```

is needed? Thanks!